# Support of WebView2 for WPF Apps

Tags: wpf, webview2, obsolete

We are developing an App in WPF and wanted to embed HTML page in it. We have planned to use WebView2 for it as it has lot of advantages like easy debugging, host to WebView and vice versa communication, etc... Before started using WebView2, we would like to understand the support roadmap of WebView2 for WPF Apps.

Whether WebView2 will be supported for the long term? if yes, any idea how long the support is going to be?

Answer (score 2):

WebView2 does support WPF. There is a WPF control in the WebView2 nuget package.  See [Getting started with WebView2 in WPF apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf).

WPF is a popular UI framework and there is no plan to drop support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for not being very clear in my question. As you have mentioned, I am using the control of the WebView2 NuGet package in my WPF app. My question is, **Is WebView2 be supported for the long term?** Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> if yes, any idea how long the support is going to be?

It's not determined but WebView2 generally follows the same Lifecycle as Microsoft Edge so yes, you can count on it being supported long-term: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-edge-webview2